# Ensuring that Lock goes from Process A to Process B

Tags: locks

Let's say process A has an exclusive lock on some shared resource. Is there a way to ensure that after it completes execution, Process B will definitely get the lock (as compared to say, process C being able to get it)?

I am coding in a language that is relatively less used, but didn't want to limit my question to a language-specific tag (in case there are any language-agnostic ways of ensuring the above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with a single mutex, but you could use some semaphores in addition to (or instead of) the mutex. Basically, when `A` is finished, it would signal `B's` semaphore. When `B` or `C` is finished, it signals an 'everyone else' semaphore. `A` and `C` wait on the 'everyone else' semaphore before using the shared resource.

Comment: What do you mean by "B's semaphore" or "Everyone else semaphore"? I was under the impression that a semaphore is a property of the lock-able object and not a property of each thread.

Comment: B's semaphore is the semaphore B waits on and A posts to. The other semaphore is waited on by every other thread and posted by every thread except A. A semaphore is a standalone thing. It neither belongs to a thread nor an object.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Unless your language or library makes such a guarantee, you shall not assume that another process will get the lock.  You should not either take a gamble on which other process could acquire the lock.

**[Starvation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starvation_(computer_science))** could for example occur, if process A is too fast to re-acquire the lock while process B is still waiting,  or if the process scheduler is not well designed, which might result in B not getting the opportunity to acquire the lock.

*Note:  I assumed that there would be no deadlock since you said that A could finish its processing (and hence not be stuck waiting for another lock)*